# How to draw a canvas on canvas using the drawImage method?

Tags: javascript, canvas

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>




const network = document.createElement('canvas')
const ctx_network = network.getContext('2d');
ctx_network.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx_network.fillRect(0, 0, 250, 250);
ctx_network.fillStyle = 'green';
ctx_network.fillRect(250, 250, 250, 250);
ctx_network.fillStyle = 'aqua';
ctx_network.fillRect(0, 250, 250, 250);
ctx_network.fillStyle = 'violet';
ctx_network.fillRect(250, 0, 250, 250);

const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.drawImage(network, 200, 200, 200, 200, 0, 0, 200, 200);
```

Why am I not displaying anything ?

I specified the values in the drawImage method to see the middle of the canvas on which I drew 4 squares, but I don't see any of them.